# Horizontal and vertical scrolling while the button stays at the bottom

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app which has a activity where custom data can be shown.

I need horizontal and vertical `scrollbars` so that the data can be seen if the size is larger than the screen.

So i've tried to add a `HorizontalScrollView`, which adds the horizontal scroll, but now the button is no longer glued to the bottom of the screen. What do i do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".activities.UserModeAdvancedActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_user_mode_advanced">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout_user_mode_advanced"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAlarmOverview"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:onClick="onButtonClick"
                android:text="@string/button_show_more" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey try the following code :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:weightSum="10"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout_user_mode_advanced"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAlarmOverview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/button_show_more" />
</LinearLayout>
```